# try_emplace doesn't work (as desired) when you have an inheritance structure for the value type?

Tags: c++, c++17, emplace

```
// A couple of simple structs that inherit AND have different ctor arguments
struct A 
{ 
  A(int) {} 
};

// Note that "B" is a subclass of "A", which is important below
struct B : A 
{
  B(int, char) : A(0) // The 0 doesn't matter
  {}
  // Note that B has no data members that "will be chopped"
};

// A simple map... Note the value type is "A"
// There should be no problem putting B's in here though because they are a subclass of A
// And as noted above, B has no additional members that will be chopped
// (
std::unordered_map<int, A> map;

// This works as expected, because we're trying to emplace an object of type "A"
auto [_, success] = map.try_emplace(
  5, // the key
  6  // the single argument to A's ctor
);
assert(success);

// This compiles BUT:
// 1. It's attempting to overwrite the key used above (5), and so
//    the emplace correctly fails
// 2. Uh oh though -- Obviously a "B" is constructed and destructed though
//    the emplace fails
auto [_, success] = map.try_emplace(
  5,
  B{5, 6} // The map knows the value type as "A", which means I only
          // have the option of passing A's ctor args, not B's.  This doesn't
          // do what I want when I'm emplacing a "B"... In fact, this creates
          // an rvalue of type "B" (duh) and then destructs it when the emplace fails.
          //
          // So my question is:  How can I pass the arguments for B's ctor
          // to a map that expects an "A" (keep in mind B is a subclass of A)
);
assert(!success);
```

To respond to a few of the posters:

1. I am aware that B will get sliced if it is stored as an A in the map.  That is why I specifically mention that there are no additional data members in B.
2. Yes, I am absolutely trying to make sure that B does not get constructed if the insert would fail.  The only way I could get it to compile was to construct a B then shove it in the map.  So that's not the map's fault :)
3. So the only real difference between B and A is their ctor.

Comment: It seems that you are asking how to postpone the construction of the `B` object until after it is known that the insertion will succeed. If that's correct, you should be a little bit more clear about it.

Comment: You can't store a `B` in a map that has `A`s... so not really sure what the goal is here.

Comment: Even though "B has no additional members", it still gets sliced, which means a move/copy constructor of `A` must be invoked with the temporary `B` as argument, and then there is no actual `B` object alive within the `unordered_map`.

Comment: Good points all -- I responded with an addendum above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put a B into an A.

You can **slice** a B into an A.  Slicing refers to copying the A part of B into an A object,

In C++ variables are their type.  They are not a different type, even if that other type would fit in the storage.

Pointers and references can refer to the base class component of a class.  But values are always what they are.

There is no way to store a B in that map.

Now if you are ok with slicing, we can defer the construction of the B until emplace finds a spot for it.  The B constructed will then be sliced and the A part moved into storage, then destroyed.

```
template<class F>
struct ctor{
  F f;
  template<class T>
  operator T()&&{
    return std::move(f)();
  }
};
template<class F>
ctor(F)->ctor<F>;
```

now just:

```
auto [_, success] = map.try_emplace(
  5,
  ctor{[&]{return B{5, 6};}}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is: How can I pass the arguments for B's ctor to a map that expects an "A" (keep in mind B is a subclass of A)

You cannot. As a workaround, you can first check where the node would be inserted, and then if it isn't there, use it as a hint to insert the element:

```
const auto it = map.lower_bound(5);
if (it == map.end() || it->first != 5) {
    map.insert(it, std::make_pair(5, B{5, 6}));
}
```

Using the insertion hint avoids having to walk down the tree a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your example a bit.

```
void foo(bool b, int* a) {
    if (b) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        a[i] = i + 42;
}

foo (rand() == 42, std::array<int, 1000>().data());
```

Do you expect that the compiler will omit creation of `std::array<int, 1000>` if `foo` fails to use it?

If you want a big array to be created only if `foo` goes past the first `return` statement, then it's up to you to create a big array only when `foo` goes past the first `return` statement. There are many ways to do that, but hoping that the compiler will magically do it for you is not one of them. You need to change `foo` so that it creates a big array when it needs one.

Going back to your example, you have asked for creation of a temporary object of type `B` by writing `B{5, 6}`, and you've got a temporary object of type `B`, regardless of whether `emplace` succeeds or not. This is true for any other object that you pass to `emplace`.

```
  map.try_emplace(5, 5);         // 5 is always constructed
  map.try_emplace(5, A{5});      // A{5} is always constructed
  map.try_emplace(5, B{5, 6});   // B{5, 6} is always constructed
```

If you want to construct a `B` object only if `emplace` succeeds, you need to move creation of `B` to a piece of code that is executed when `emplace` succeeds. The constructor of `A` is a good place for that.

Switching to a lazy-evaluation language such as Haskell is another (radical) solution to this problem.