# Why does overload resolution prefer a move constructor over a non-special constructor when equally good conversion functions are available?

Tags: c++, c++17, overload-resolution

The following program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{ 
  A() { std::cout << "A()\n"; }
  A(int) { std::cout << "A(int)\n"; }
};

struct C {
  operator int() {
    std::cout << "operator int\n";
    return 42;
  }
  operator A() {
    std::cout << "operator A\n";
    return A();
  }
};

int main() {
    auto a = A{C{}};
};
```

compiles and, when run, prints:

```
operator A
A()
```

See [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/qaYvav).

This shows that the move constructor of `A` was selected to perform the initialization, with `C::operator A()` being invoked to convert `C` into the type that the move constructor expects.

Alternatively, the `A::A(int)` constructor could have been selected, with `C::operator int()` being invoked. But `A::A(int)` loses overload resolution, apparently.

Why does this happen? I am not able to see any rule in the standard that explains why the move constructor of `A` wins the overload resolution.

(This question is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66307077/481267); I could not understand why the code in that answer works.)

Comment: I think because going via `int` requires 2 conversions but the standard only allows for 1

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't think that's why. Only one user-defined conversion is allowed to convert the argument type into the parameter type. In both cases, there is one user-defined conversion, namely the conversion operator. The call to the constructor of `A` that is ultimately selected by the overload resolution process doesn't count. That occurs after the overload resolution is done.

Comment: It seems that the compiler will not pick `A(int)` due to copy elision, but I am not sure where does that rule come from.

Comment: It does seem like mandatory-copy-elision is causing the move constructor to be preferred. Based on this [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86521), and [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1155r3.html) it seems that's the intent but the standard is not very clear about it. Some (but not all) wording from that proposal seems to be merged into the working draft, so perhaps the current working draft resolves the ambiguity; I can't tell.

Comment: @cigien I don't understand the relevance of the proposal. It seems to be all about replacing copies with moves, not eliding moves entirely.

Comment: I'm looking at [this section](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1155r3.html#wording) which refers to copy-initialization contexts. There's also wording about a second round of overload resolution if the first fails, which seems relevant here. I could be wrong about that.

Comment: @cigien "In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation..." Nothing about eliding moves.

Comment: Ok, probably not relevant then. The last line of comment#6 in the bug report does seem relevant, but I could be wrong about that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that both GCC and Clang implemented a fix for [CWG2327](https://wg21.link/CWG2327) by directly considering conversion functions to *cv* T as candidates when initializing an object of type *cv2* T, in addition to constructors.

When `C::operator A()` is considered as a candidate itself, it is an exact match, and therefore prevails over the constructor call which requires a user-defined conversion.

That issue is still in drafting status, so you won't be finding this in the wording.

Notably both reject with `-std=c++14`.